# Perl - update contents of a file by adding 1 on the first column

Tags: perl, updates

I am looking for a better way to add 1 on contents on the first column in a file. I read a file and update contents on the first column by adding 1.

my input file: (sparc_export.test)

```
export
3066
10500 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
10500 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
10500 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
10500 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
10500 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
10500 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
```

... It would be more than 3000 lines.

I wanted to the file would be: (sparc_export.test)

```
export
3066
10501 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
10501 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
10501 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
10501 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
10501 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
10501 cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
```

I am reading the file as a 2x2 array and add 1 for each content from the 3rd line to the end, but I think this is not a good way. Please let me know a better way to update contents of a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;




    my $exportname="sparc_export.test";

    #### read sparc_export.test
    open(CSV,$exportname)||die("Cannot open export file $!");
    my @export;
    while(<CSV>){
        my @row=split(/ /,$_);
        push(@export,\@row);
    }

    for (my $i=2; $i < (scalar @export); $i +=1) {
            $export[$i][0]= $export[$i][0]+1;
    }


open(my $fh4, '>', 'sparc_export.test');
print $fh4 join("\n", @export);
close $fh4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done very easily with just a short command rather than a full program:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1 + 1/e if $. > 2' sparc_export.test > sparc_export_incremented.test
```

The `-p` flag wraps the entire program in a while loop over the lines of the input file, and the `if $. > 2` restricts the modifications to lines where the line number is greater than 2.

In response to your comments:

To replace the original file rather than create a new one, you could say:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(\d+)/$1 + 1/e if $. > 2' sparc_export.test
```

That would save the original file under the name `sparc_export.test.bak`.  You can say just `-i` instead of `-i.bak` to not create a backup file.

It would be very odd to call out to a Perl command from within a Perl program, but it can be done:

```
system('perl', '-i.bak', '-pe', 's/(\d+)/$1 + 1/e if $. > 2', 'sparc_export.test');
```

More typically one would do the work inside the main program:

```
open my $in, '<', 'sparc_export.test' or die "Can't open file: $!";
open my $out, '>', 'sparc_export.test.out' or die "Can't open file: $!";
while (<$in>) {
  s/(\d)/$1 + 1/e if $. > 2;
  print $out $_;
}
close $out;
close $in;
rename 'sparc_export.test.out', 'sparc_export.test' or die "Failed to rename: $!";
```

Comment: That's great.  One quick question. How do I do If I just update the file, not to create a new file?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. Is it possible to call the one-liner in a top perl script. I used:  system('perl',$script)==0 or die "failed to execute $script: \$?=$?";  to call another perl script in a top perl script, but I don't know how to call the one-liner perl.

Comment: That will work only if leading zeros are not present, or are not considered significant by any downstream programs that process the file.  A line starting `00100 ...` would come out `101 ...`

Comment: True, but exploring every unstated contingency is unwarranted in general IMHO.

Comment: @Sean Thank you. The last one is what I wanted. Thank you.